# Dynamic filters in Spring Boot query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to make a dynamic filter only query using Spring Boot and JPA with a SQL Database, but I don't know what to do.

We are doing one query for each filter, but that way is a bad way.
So we need one query for all filters.

How do I do it?

Comment: What's a consulter?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, it's a query.

Comment: You can generate dynamic queries using the Criteria API, for example https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the old and popular CriteriaBuilder or use the most sophisticated **Specification concept in Spring Data JPA**, or you can use the implementation of QueryDSL which give you better efficient way. All of them can make your life easy by given you  a dynamic programmatically way to gemerate your filter in Runtime.